# Return a name through an API call in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

using React.js I am trying to display the artist names that are given through an API call.

I have a class component called ArtistList that is being called on my main index.js page, and I'm trying to use the artist usernames in the API data to update the component's state.

No matter what I try I seem to keep getting the same error message with this in my browser console:

**Uncaught TypeError: this.state.artist.map is not a function**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class ArtistList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {artist: []};
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.ArtistList();
 }

 ArtistList() {
   axios.get('https://api-v2.hearthis.at/feed/?type=popular&page=1&count=20')
     .then((data) => this.setState({ artist: data }));
 }

 render() {
   const artists = this.state.artist.map((item) => (
     <div>
       <h1>{ item.user.username }</h1>
     </div>
   ));

   return (
     <div className="layout-content-wrapper">
       <div className="panel-list">{ artists }</div>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`axios`'s API returns a `response` object with `data` being one of the properties, so change it to

```
axios.get('https://api-v2.hearthis.at/feed/?type=popular&page=1&count=20')
  .then(({ data }) => this.setState({ artist: data }));
```

Comment: You haven't changed anything.

Comment: I added `{}` around `data`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: ES6 Destructuring. Nice :)

Comment: Oh my god you are the best that totally worked! after pulling your hair out for ages it's always just ONE LITTLE THING!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

The axios Promise resolves to be a response object. The `data` property contains the payload. Try this:

```
axios.get('https://api-v2.hearthis.at/feed/?type=popular&page=1&count=20')
  .then((response) => this.setState({
    artist: response.data
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code(your code looks fine), your axios's API is having some problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/RanjeetKumarGautam/69z2wepo/183143/

```
class ArtistList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {artist: []};
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.ArtistList();
 }

 ArtistList() {
   this.setState({ artist: [{user:{username: 'john'}},{user:{username: 'ken'}}] });
 }

 render() {
   const artists = this.state.artist.map((item) => (
     <div key={item.user.username}>
       <h1>{ item.user.username }</h1>
     </div>
   ));

   return (
     <div className="layout-content-wrapper">
       <div className="panel-list">{ artists }</div>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class ArtistList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
       this.state = {
          artist: [];
       }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        const res = await axios.get('https://api-v2.hearthis.at/feed/?type=popular&page=1&count=20');
        const artist = await res.data;
        this.setState({artist});
    }
    renderArtists = () => {
        if(this.state.artist.length!=0){
            return this.state.artist.map(item => {
                return (
                   <div>
                     <h1>{ item.user.username }</h1>
                   </div>
                )
            });
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
           <div className="layout-content-wrapper">
             <div className="panel-list">{this.renderArtist()}</div>
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```